# Where is the arduino source folder on Mac's Arduino.app?

Tags: macos, arduino

I am building my arduino project using Arduino-Makefile. Arduino-Makefile requires avr-g++, which is conveniently located at inside the `arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin` inside the linux distribution folder.

Mac Arduino packages everything inside a .app file and I can't seem to find the arduino folder on mac. Where is it located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/path/to/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++`